# Create multidimensional numpy array from specific keys of dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, vectorization

I have dictionary like this:

```
a = dict(zip( ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'], 
          ... [ [1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40], [100,200,300,400], [1000,2000,3000,4000]])

>>> a
{'k1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'k2': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'k3': [100, 200, 300, 400], 'k4': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]}
```

What I want to do: **get values for several keys and create multidimensional numpy array from them**. Something like this:

```
result = numpy.array( [a[x] for x in ('k1' , 'k3')]
```

I tried this code:

```
ar = numpy.array([])
for el in ['k1', 'k3']:
     ar = numpy.r_[ar, num_dict[el]]
ar = ar.reshape(2,len(ar)/2)
```

But are there some built in functions or more elegant ways?

Comment: I consider your first option pretty elegant already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need exactly one numpy array from data, so I can't find the way without loops.
I create function:

```
def loadFromDict( fieldnames, dictionary ):
    ''' fieldnames - list of needed keys, dictionary - dict for extraction
     result - numpy.array size of (number of keys, lengths of columns in dict)'''
    ar = numpy.zeros( (len(fieldnames), len(dictionary[fieldnames[0]])) )
    for c,v in enumerate(fieldnames,0):
        ar[c,:] = dictionary[v]
    return ar
```

In my case dictionary has the same length for all columns. Anyway it is easy to implement either they are different: use `[len(v) for v in dictionary.values()]` to get all lengths, or find lengths for current keys.

Answer (score 1):

A list of lists is normal input to `np.array`, so your list comprehension makes sense.

```
In [382]: [a[x] for x in ['k1','k3']]
Out[382]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```

Or for the whole dictionary

```
In [385]: np.array(list(a.values()))    # list required in py3
Out[385]: 
array([[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
       [   1,    2,    3,    4],
       [  10,   20,   30,   40],
       [ 100,  200,  300,  400]])
```

Normally dictionary items are selected one by one as in the comprehension.  `operator` has a convenience class for fetching several keys with one call (I don't think it makes much difference in speed):

```
In [386]: import operator
In [387]: operator.itemgetter('k1','k3')(a)
Out[387]: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [100, 200, 300, 400])
```

I don't think the iteration with `r_` is a good choice.  `r_` is just a cover for `concatenate`.  If you must iterate, repeated `concatante` is slower.  It's better to build a list, and make the array at the end (as in the list comprehension).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `itemgetter` is awesome function and I already want to use it!